# How do I add an input field to the form->create method globally in cakephp 1.2

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I am trying to add a hidden input on all of my forms as a part of $form->create() function (kinda like how rails does) so I can add in a custom csrf token.

Is there anyway I can override the helper to add a input after it?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way will be to add the [security component](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Security-Component.html) cake provides.

> By using the Security Component you automatically get CSRF and form tampering protection. Hidden token fields will automatically be inserted into forms and checked by the Security component.

Comment: Well, I looked into that. Problem is some of my get actions change resources and the security component only does checks on post/put/destroy actions.

Comment: get actions change resources?

Comment: I'm not sure about this since I've never used that version of cakephp, but looking at the api it does seems like [get actions are included](http://api.cakephp.org/1.2/source-class-SecurityComponent.html#199-208) in the component

Comment: @looneydoodle that *is* unfortunate? You should **never** use 'get' forms to modify your data. What is holding you from changing that into 'post' forms?

Comment: the fact that the application is way too huge to go through every line and fix get actions changing resources

Comment: You *do* realise that a friendly Google Bot that crawls your site will also inadvertently make changes or even *delete* data? [Google Bot deleting my database entries!](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Google-Bot-deleting-my-database-entries-td1277935.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing that anyway i.e. in the way you asked the question (form->create). Create a helper and use that, you can also store the CSRF in the user's session if you are wondering where to put the value.

Comment: Regardless of wether its right or not, how do I override the helper's create method to do more stuff after its done doing what it usually does?

Answer (score 0):

### Overriding Core Helpers via Aliases in CakePHP 2.x

In CakePHP 2.x its possible to overriding the default helpers by using an 'alias' for your own helper. This will allow your to create a 'drop-in' replacement for the built-in CakePHP helpers without changing the rest of your code.

For example:

app/Controller/AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array(
        'Form' => array(
            'className' => 'FancyFormHelper'
        )
    );
}
```

app/View/Helper/FancyFormHelper.php

```
App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');

class FancyFormHelper extends FormHelper {
    
    public function create($model = null, $options = array())
    {
        $output = parent::create($model, $options);

        // append your hidden fields 
        return $output . $this->createCSRFfield(); // Or whatever you name your method
    }
}
```

Documentation: [Using and Configuring Helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-and-configuring-helpers)